# Message[Forbidden] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[youtube.video]

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#retrieve_my_uploads as a framework and try to change the description of each video. I changed two parts

```
credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
    // user's account, but not other types of account access.
    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl },
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
);
```

and

```
foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
{
    if (playlistItem.Snippet.Description.Contains("something"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", playlistItem.Snippet.Title, playlistItem.Snippet.Description);
        Video video = new Video();
        VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
        snippet.Description = "new string";
        video.Snippet = snippet;
        video.Status = status;
        var videosUpdateRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Update(video, "snippet,status");
        Video response = videosUpdateRequest.Execute();
    }
}
```

But I get

```
Error: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Forbidden [403]
Errors [
        Message[Forbidden] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[youtube.video]
]
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: If you check the [core api error](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#gdata.CoreErrorDomain) in the General API error section of YouTube documentation, it is referring to the improper authorization of the request. Make sure that you are properly [implementing OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication).

Comment: My code was working with no issues until today. After a few days of going over my Google api quota, today I resume the service and now I am getting this error. Nothing is changed in terms of oAuth or any credentials.